# Trouble with indices when trying to standardize columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, indexing

I need to standardize each column in this data frame, but using a for loop seems to give me isseus with the indeces. Here is my code:

```
m=length(data[1,])
n=length(data[,1])
for (i in (1:m)){
        column = data[,i]
        mean=mean(column)
        sd=sd(column)
        for (j in (1:n)){
                data[j,i]=(data[j,i]-mean)/sd
        }
}
```

Which gives this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(data, , i) :
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'i' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..i]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
Calls: [ -> [.data.table
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You are using a `data.table` which is different from a `data.frame`. Just change your data.table to dataframe. ie before you start the process, do `data <- as.data.frame(data)`. Lastly you could simply do `scale(data)` and that will scale the data for you